# UIImageview won't center in superview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, center, subview

I have an UIImageView which I add to a UIView to enhance the area where touches are recognized.  When I try to center the UIImageView in the UIView (code below) the center is set  properly but when I run the program the image is shown way off outside the frame of the UIView.

Any ideas?

```
// image size is 32x32 pixels but view will be created with 44x44 so touch recognition is better
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, 44, 44)];

if (self) {
    switch (color) {
        case Blue:
            self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_red"]];
            break;
        case Green:
            self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_green"]];
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self setCenter:position];
    [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];        
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.imageView setCenter:position];

    NSLog(@"uiview center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.center));
    NSLog(@"image center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.imageView.center));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The imageview setCenter is relative to its parent. Try:

```
[self.imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but if i try   [self.imageView setCenter:self.center]  the result is the same :-(

Comment: Thats not what I was suggesting.  You need to get a point that is relative to the parent.  self.center will return it relative to its parent, and shouldn't work

Comment: but self is the superview and so it's the parent in this case. Or am i wrong?

Comment: It will report it in its parent coordinates.  There is always UIWindow at the very top level

Comment: ahh, now i got it :-)  `[self.imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))];` did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *imageforFace=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2, 125,125)];
imageforFace.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[imageforFace setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
imageforFace.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageforFace];
```

**Final the output is**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**try this code to give the UIImageView Frame *Centre of UIView***

**1) in .h file**

```
UIImageView *imgCenter;
```

**2) in .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imgCenter=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2, 35, 35)];
    [imgCenter setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"centerImage.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgCenter];
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imgCenter=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
    imgCenter.center = self.view.center;
    [imgCenter setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"centerImage.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgCenter];
}
```